# Link a search bar cell label to view controller

Tags: xcode, search, view, controller

I am trying to create a search bar in Xcode so when you search for an item, you can click on the search result cell and it will go to a view controller but all it is doing now is going to the sea view controller and just displaying the label of the cell i clicked on.

**Here is my .m file**

```
@interface ListTableViewController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dataArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *searchResults;

@end

@implementation ListTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Tomb Raider", @"Little Big Planet",     @"Unchanted 3", @"BlackOps 2", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText: (NSString *) searchText
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
self.searchResults = [self.dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    return [self.dataArray count];
} else { // (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    return  [self.searchResults count];
}

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
}



#pragma mark - Table view delegate

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetails"]) {
    DetailsViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

    if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        dvc.sendLabel = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return;
    } else{
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        dvc.sendLabel = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return;
    }
}
}


@end
```

Thanks, anything will help.

Comment: I don't wanna write instead of you all controller code, but I think if you read this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/ you should find the answer.

Comment: I have tried that tutorial and it has the same problem.

Comment: you can not pushing new view controller, or what? seriously I not understand you. Please specify your problem

Comment: When the user searches a term i would like them to click on the term and have them be directed to a view controller which will display different information for each search term. Also, not just a label.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement this delegate method :

```
// Method returns the clicked row.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   YourPushedViewController *ypVC = [[YourPushedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourPushedViewController" bundle:nil];
  ypVC.selectedText = myResultArray[indexPath.row]; 


   [self.navigationController pushViewController:ypVC animated:YES]; 

}
```

That method is response for selecting row and passing selected result to another view.

This is hint for you :[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Ive tried this and it keeps saying "use of undeclared identifier 'myresultarray' " 
    
The part I'm having trouble with is below -   
ypVC.ypvcText = myResultArray[indexPath.row];

Comment: Of course, because the myResultArray it's my own variable you must exchange this variable by your custom array. And the YourPushedViewController its my ViewController, you must add into project your custom ViewController with public property selectedText

Comment: Ok but what would i change myResultArray to. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Here You have a good tutorial about search bar : http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview if You will have still problem with this task, I will create for you a sample code. But first try to solve this problem alone, I will have free time to do it in a few days. This tutorial is quite good. Good luck

Comment: Tried the tutorial, didn't work. If you could provide me with some sample code in your free time that would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I write it for you at the weekend.

Comment: Sure it's - mattsuff@hotmail.com

Comment: app must be based on storyboard or .xib?

Comment: App will be based on Storyboard.

Comment: Hey, have you had a chance to send the email yet?